# How to make tooltip in JQuery for a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone knows how to make tooltip for textbox? Like the image below:

[image]

I want the tooltip be positioned at the near-right of the textbox, plus with some animation.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BeautyTips](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/bt) does just that.

[image]